# Button will not show in AVD on Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and i have been trying to get the button to work but on my device it wouldn't show but on my design page it's there but no errors show up.

the design layout

[image: the design layout]

the code

[image: the code]

the AVD

[image: the AVD]

Answer (score 0):

Remove either `layout_marginTop` or `layout_constraintVertical_bias` attribute from the Button, according to the design requirements. Bias moves the button to the very bottom of the screen, and margin moves it event lower, out of the visible are.

P.S. do not trust AS layout preview, it lies sometimes :)